# Integral of an analytic function f over a closed curve which is homotopic to a point in the domain of f.

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem states that if $f$ is nonzero and analytic on a region $A$, and if $\gamma$ is closed and homotopic to a point in $A$, then $\displaystyle\int_{\gamma} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}dz = 0$

My approach is to use the fact that since $f$ is analytic on $A$ then so too is $f'$ on $A$, and since $f$ is nonzero, $g = \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}$ is continuous and analytic on $A$ and so we can use the antiderivate theorem and deduce that the integral of this function on a closed curve is zero. Is this the right approach? Does the fact that $\gamma$ is homotopic to a point in $A$ help in any way?

Comment: What is "the antiderivate theorem"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the annulus with inner radius $1/2$ and outer radius $2$, $D=\operatorname{Ann}(1/2, 2)$. Consider $f(z)=z^{-1}$ then clearly $f$ is analytic and nonzero on $D$, but
\begin{align}
\int_{|z|=1} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\ dz =&\ -\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z}\ dz \\
=&\ -\int^{2\pi}_0 e^{-i\theta} ie^{i\theta}\ d\theta = -2\pi i. 
\end{align}

Suppose $\gamma$ is homotopic to a point $p \in D$, i.e. 
\begin{align}
H(t, z) = (1-t)\gamma(z)+tp
\end{align}
is continuous on $[0, 1]\times D$, then we see that
\begin{align}
\int_\gamma \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\ dz = \int_{H(t)} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\ dz
\end{align}
for all $t \in [0, 1]$. In particular, we see that
\begin{align}
\left|\int_{H(t)} \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)}\ dz\right| \leq&\ \int_{H(t)} \frac{|f'(z)|}{|f(z)|}\ |dz| \\
\leq&\ \left(\left|\frac{f'(p)}{f(p)}\right|+\varepsilon\right)\operatorname{Length}\left(H(t) \right)\\
\leq&\  C(1-t)\left(\left|\frac{f'(p)}{f(p)}\right|+\varepsilon\right) \
\end{align}
for $t$ sufficiently close to $1$.